# How to post form data to test multer node.js application in SoapUI

Tags: node.js, soapui, multer

js application using multer npm package. The code looks like below:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'avatars' })

router.post('/users/me/avatar', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    res.send()
})
```

I am trying to test this endpoint using SoapUi.

[image: screenshot of the request I am sending bySoapUi]

However, I am getting the below below response from node.

> MulterError: Unexpected field
> at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
> at Busboy. (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
> at Busboy.emit (events.js:311:20)
> at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
> at PartStream. (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire
> Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
> at PartStream.emit (events.js:311:20)
> at HeaderParser. (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire
> Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
> at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:311:20)
> at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
> at SBMH. (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
> at SBMH.emit (events.js:311:20)
> at SBMH._sbmh_feed (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:95:16)
> at SBMH.push (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)
> at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)
> at Dicer._oninfo (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)
> at SBMH. (C:\Users\pdatta\OneDrive - American Tire Distributors\Node\task-manager\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)

Please help me resolve this. The file is not being saved in the destination directory.

Please let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0):

Try this as middleware

```js
const multer  = require('multer')

const dirStorage =  __dirname +'/avatas';

const storageOption = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, req.dirStorageUser);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `new_avatar.png`);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: storageOption
}).single('upload');


router.post('/users/me/avatar', uploadMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.send("");
})


function uploadMiddleware(req, res, next) {

    if (!fs.existsSync(dirStorage)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(dirStorage);
    }

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      let errorMsg;
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        errorMsg = 'Was not possible save image';
      } else if (err) {
        errorMsg = 'Something was wrong on save image';
      }
   
      if (errorMsg) {
        return res.send(errorMsg);
      }
      return res.send("success");
      //next("route");
    });

}
```

:

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got this response back from the server - "Was not possible save image". Could anyone check my SoapUi request from the screenshot as I am sure if i am doing correct or not. Thanks

Comment: Sorry man. Change .single('upload') for .single('avatar') your field. And check if your folder is allowed for write

Comment: I am getting this error. I need to verify my SoapUi request from the screenshot by someone.
internal/validators.js:117
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);